# Return the type of a extended class give platform declaration clash

Tags: java, kotlin

I have the following declaration:

```
val selectedPhotos: MutableLiveData<List<Photo>> = MutableLiveData()
```

I have the following method that should return the selectedPhotos which is a MutableLiveData type.

```
fun getSelectedPhotos(): MutableLiveData<List<Photo>> {
    return selectedPhotos
}
```

However, the following give me an error:

```
Platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (getSelectedPhotos()Landroidx/lifecycle/MutableLiveData;):
    fun <get-selectedPhotos>(): MutableLiveData<List<Photo>> defined in com.raywenderlich.android.combinestagram.SharedViewModel
    fun getSelectedPhotos(): MutableLiveData<List<Photo>> defined in com.raywenderlich.android.combinestagram.SharedViewModel
```

However, If I change the fun to return the following everything works ok:

```
fun getSelectedPhotos(): LiveData<List<Photo>> {
    return selectedPhotos
}
```

However, looking at the following MutableLiveData extends LiveData

```
public class MutableLiveData<T> extends LiveData<T> {
...
}
```

Just confused about why I can't use `MutableLiveData` as the return type which is the correct type that I have declared.

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare something in kotlin, the kotlin creates it's setter and getter for you. So considering you declare `var abc`, kotlin will declare `setAbc` and `getAbc`, which is very handful for data classes.

In your case since your property name is **selectedPhotos**, kotlin would have already created a getter with name **getSelectedPhotos** with return type **MutableLiveData>**. Due to this, you are getting clash as two methods have same name and return type.

In your case, you don't need to declare this `getSelectedPhotos` explicitly, as the kotlin has already declared that for you. You can access that getter and setter declared by kotlin in both kotlin and JAVA class.

Edit:
In case, you want to look into the generated JAVA class for your kotlin file, open your kotlin file and then go to **Tools** -> **Kotlin** -> **Show Kotlin Bytecode** and then click on **Decomplie** button present on opened screen.